# Multidimensional array check for undefined keys

Tags: javascript

I have the following array generated by PHP:

```
{
    "101265" : {
        "1" : {
            "1" : 165,
            "2" : 120
        },
        "2" : {
            "10" : 5
        }
    },
    "101382" : {
        "1" : {
            "1" : 810,
            "2" : 120
        }
    },
    "101388" : {
        "1" : {
            "13" : 240
        }
    },
    "101449" : {
        "70" : {
            "127" : 30
        }
    }
}
```

In order for me to avoid `undefined variable` error when trying to access 
`totalTimePerRate[ticketId][serviceId][serviceRateId]`

I have to use the following checks:

```
var totalTime = (typeof totalTimePerRate[ticketId] !== 'undefined') ? (typeof totalTimePerRate[ticketId][serviceId] !== 'undefined') ? (typeof totalTimePerRate[ticketId][serviceId][serviceRateId] !== 'undefined') ? totalTimePerRate[ticketId][serviceId][serviceRateId] : false : false : false;
```

Otherwise it will throw an error if such ticketId, serviceId or serviceRateId not found.

Could you please advise on how to minimize the code of such checks?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post JSON-formatted not PHP-formatted sample objects to JavaScript questions.

Comment: @Bergi: I looked at that question before I posted, this is not my case.

Comment: Can you elaborate how your case is any different?

Comment: Just realized that I'm actually using objects... In my other script I use array, but this should work for this case.. =)